# In CSS, why vertically centered text shows up lower and lower inside of <span> or <a>?

Tags: css

A usual way to vertically center some inline text or image is

```
#one-div { font: 16px/16px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif }
#one-div * { vertical-align: middle }
```

with the HTML of

```
<div id="one-div">
    hello <span>world</span> try 
    <a href="http://www.google.com">more</a>
    <span><span><span>see</span></span></span>
</div>
```

see sample at: http://jsfiddle.net/934Zu/2/

It can be compared to: http://jsfiddle.net/934Zu/1/

This is an example how they are vertically centered: http://jsfiddle.net/934Zu/6/

Why do elements inside of `<span>` or `<a>` get displayed lower and lower?  The `<span>` doesn't have padding or margin or border, so no vertical space should be there.

What might be a way to fix it so that the line of text (and images, if inside `<span>` and/or `<a>`) can be vertically aligned perfectly? (other than putting everything in the same level of nested `<span>` or `<a>`, which might not be a totally elegant fix)

(and more importantly, why did it get lower and lower in the first place?)

Comment: being polite will do you infinite good

Comment: can you see http://jsfiddle.net/934Zu/6/ for what vertically centered is

Comment: Why are people down-voting this?

Comment: @Sime, because Sebastian Patane Masuelli gave an answer not related to vertically centered and got a down vote for his answer, so he deleted his answer, and then down voted this question.  And then he added the comment to tell other people to be polite.

Comment: @Sebastian Is that true?

Comment: @Šime the former is, the latter is not I think: He meant the OP. I downvoted this because I find it rude for the OP to downvote answers, especially if as much effort is put in as in @Sebastiane's case, and it was an innocent misunderstanding. Would downvote again

Comment: @動靜能量 I have asked for a moderator to look into this. We'll see...

Comment: @動靜能量, i misunderstood your question (which wasnt' very clearly, stated). then proceeded to give three possitlbe solutions, and each time i did you insulted me.  i was in the process of trying a fourth solution when i just deleted my answer and gave up

Comment: @Sime i undeleted my answer, judge for yourself.  Its really not that important.  @動靜能量 : i hope you get your answer, the last thingi want is to start a flame war.  I did downvote your question because i felt you were being rude when i was trying to help you.

Comment: @動靜能量 next time, maybe start by using more exact wording. "Vertically align" != "vertically center" and +1 for @Sebastian for being consistently nice

Comment: I think I might have an answer for you, but I'm not going to post it because if it's wrong you will just downvote me.

Comment: @Pekka @Sebastian I thought that questions should be down-voted only if they - the questions - are bad for some reason. I'm not sure that they should be used to down-vote the user who asked the question. The question itself is actually quite interesting.

Comment: I sometimes answer questions and gave a not exactly correct answer, and get a downvote too.  why are you not being to able to accept a downvote if an answer isn't correct?

Comment: His answer IS correct though. Put a border around your text and you will see.

Comment: @動靜能量 If I take ten minutes' time or more to answer somebody's hazily worded question, and the OP downvotes me because of a misunderstanding, that person goes straight onto my list of people whose questions I will *never* answer again. Downvoting shallow questions, or crass errors, I can stand behind, but there is something like respect for the answerer's time and attention received, regardless of whether it solves the question or not.

Comment: @動靜能量: check out the updated answer, i think it solves it, with david's help.

Comment: see the comment down there...

Comment: So you downvoted the question purely based on the fact that you don't like how you are treated.  That is not just impolite, that is against the proper usage of the site -- you downvote a question if the question is not a good one, not based on how you feel you'd like to be treated (people cannot downvote you).  Your answer did seem somewhat rushed to get points.  If you understand the question, you will know it is not about `vertical-align: bottom`, as that is the default and the other jsfiddle sample already has it right there, and you gave an answer that achieved what exactly was in the OP.

Comment: But you say, "be polite"... and yet you are impolite and not only that, do something that is against the proper use of the site.  That's exactly what I see in the current state: people say, you should this, you should that. what is right, what is wrong.  And 70% of people don't flush their toilet (the urinals).  And you are saying people should be polite, and you are not just impolite, you are against the rule of the proper use of the site.

Comment: OP, have you ever found an answer to this question?

Answer (score 2):

final(?) answers:

http://jsfiddle.net/ctrlfrk/V9j82/2 – david's solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/934Zu/23/ - my solution.
both produce vertically centered inline elements inside a div.

<strike>`#one-div * { vertical-align:bottom }`
will do it. 
http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/934Zu/3/</strike>

the problem is that the vertical-align is being applied recursively;
here it is visuallized: http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/934Zu/4/

you can also use `#one-div * {line-height: 20px;}`
http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/934Zu/5/

Comment: no, I am looking for this effect: **vertically aligned**: http://jsfiddle.net/934Zu/6/

Comment: when your answer isn't really an answer, it prevents other people from looking into the question too.  I am looking for vertical align, and you give me a bottom align solution.

Comment: Ahahaha, I just looked into font sizing and the measurements and stuff. This IS the correct answer. 動靜能量 just doesn't get it.

Comment: no, it isn't really the right answer.  there's something missing. it's a difficult problem. this gets closer: http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/934Zu/12/  but i'm still not sure how to make the loose text align properly. thaks for the suport though!

Comment: @david How is it a correct answer http://jsfiddle.net/934Zu/15/  they are not vertically aligned

Comment: We are talking about vertically **centered**, not aligned

Comment: Sebastian, add 'border:solid black 1px;' to the style for #one-div *. The text is aligning correctly, it just looks wrong because of how lowercase characters look like they have a different center.

Comment: like this: http://jsfiddle.net/V9j82/
It's even clearer if you use capitals inside the larger text: http://jsfiddle.net/ctrlfrk/V9j82/2/

Comment: yes! combining things: here's the correct answer (i hope): http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/934Zu/23/

Comment: @dave: you got it! two different approaches, both solve it. nice! that's why i love SO.

Comment: unfortunately, your answer http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/934Zu/23/ is not vertically centering the text... their vertical mid-point should align all on a straight line... David's solution is the one... although I am wondering at the same time why the original code would not work -- why the span add addition vertical spacing to the text